# Can't append child to iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to add a `div` to a YouTube `iframe` element so that I can display things over the video. But this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
   <iframe id="player" width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jn9r0avp0fY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <script>
var player = document.getElementById('player');

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'newDiv';
div.innerHTML = 'Hello, world!';

player.appendChild(div);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

has completely no effect. I can use JavaScript to confirm that the `div` is indeed in `document.getElementById('player').children`, but when inspecting elements on the page it is nowhere to be found. Why is this happening?

**UPDATE:** So I found this website https://www.reembed.com/ which succesfully overlays their own elements above the YouTube embedded `iframe` player, but I don't know how they achieve it.

Comment: You can not do this ! end of the story.

Answer (score 1):

This you can achieve using position absolute and top,left CSS properties for that div, no need to insert the div inside the Iframe.

Comment: Most things can be done this way but I can't get things over the video when the user enters fullscreen mode. In Chrome and Safari, assigning a maximum `z-index` to overlays works, but in Firefox the trick does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to append element in the iframe.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <iframe id="player" width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jn9r0avp0fY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


    <script>
        setTimeout(function() {
            var player = document.getElementById('player');
            var iframeDocument = player.contentDocument || player.contentWindow.document;

            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = 'newDiv';
            div.style.fontSize = '50px';
            div.innerHTML = 'Hello, world!';

            if (iframeDocument) {
                var iframeContent = iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName('body');
                console.log(iframeContent);
                iframeContent[0].appendChild(div);
            }

        }, 100);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But Make sure you are accessing iframe on the same origin otherwise you will get cross-origin security issue.

check cross origin security issue 
[SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame/25098153#25098153)